# Datastudio Geomap Drilldown vs GoogleMap visualize issues

Tags: looker-studio

I was playing with DataStudio GeoMap and GoogleMap features, I used Covid US datased. I made some research what is best for showing charts via GeoMap & GoogleMap, I made report with 6 slides, each slide has Title with used method  and I found below issues:

```
1) Drill down for GeoMap not working often, state/regions not showed, 
2) in slide #2 GeoMap: used 3 Geo Dimension: Lat/Long, City, Region : how to show City names ? (and disable Latitude?)
```

Seems that best way is showing via GoogleMap (slide #6) with Bubble  dimension :Lat/Long  with Tooltip:  City > then values are showing to Cities,
only issue is how to setup default zoom region US, to avoid showing whole world ?

Here is report:
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f0201b38-c2ae-400c-8ca0-d65d001c9e3a/page/DOdRB

One note: in My old report from today somehow I was able to create report with drill down 2-layer GeoMap, used Dimension: City+Region > not accurate, many cities are missing:
https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/a729972f-97ec-4faf-8311-a49719d0826c/page/TeaRB

Trying  to import GoogleMap via embded frame, but I got this error>>

```
Google Maps cannot yet be displayed in embedded reports.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1: Google Maps & Filters

Opened the [Report above](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f0201b38-c2ae-400c-8ca0-d65d001c9e3a/page/DOdRB), exported the [Google Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713352) data to Goggle Sheets, recreated a Data Source and Report, and then had a look through; it seems that the data in the `City` field is sorted, classifying values outside the United States as `NA`, in addition, removed `0,0` values in the `Latitude_Longitude` field, thus this [Filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) does the trick:

```
Exclude City RegExp Match (NA)
AND
Exclude Latitude_Longitude RegExp Match (0,0)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4e4157fa-d574-49bf-bf99-fb1e573b353c) and GIF to demonstrate (Feel free to have a look through and edit the Report as required):

[image]

## Question 2: Geo Maps & Drill-down

The updated Filter in Question 1 should do the trick when using the [Geo Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7065037) Chart Type, with all three Geo Types - `Latitude_Longitude` `City` and `Region` working as expected using the [Drill-down](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9319405) and the Zoom area set to `United States`; adding an image of the Filter above for clarification:

[image: Filter]

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4e4157fa-d574-49bf-bf99-fb1e573b353c/page/07dRB) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

## Question 3: Embedding Map Charts

- [Geo Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7065037) can be displayed on embedded reports.
- Currently, [*Google Maps won't appear in embedded reports*](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/47203481).